# Как можно редактировать имена txt файлов в архиве zip

Tags: c#, replace, zip

Есть zip архив. В нем 1000 txt файлов. Мне надо всех их редактировать(если можно то без распаковки, просто имя поменять им)

Пример:
**name-lord**

- первая замена ame-lord (*Remove(0,1*))
- вторая замена ame-word (*Replace("-l","-w"))*
- и последняя same-word *(Добавить букву в начале имени файла)*

Как сделать через c# ?

В какой архив закинул там и будет выполнятся алгоритм....

Comment: Очевидно: распаковать архив, обработать файлы, упаковать изменённые файлы назад в архив. Без распаковки, хотя бы в память, нельзя. Точно так же, как нельзя редактировать нераспакованный JPEG, например.

Comment: Редактировать файлы ну то что внутри я могу, а вот название пока не удается

Comment: @VladD JPEG можно при поворачивать и обрезать без распаковки. Так что некоторое редактирование все же возможно.

Comment: @gbg: угу, и с архивами так же по идее. Что-то можно редактировать без распаковки (имена файлов, наверное). PS: точно, у вас ответ именно об этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя библиотеку [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), можно сделать так:

Пример взять [отсюда](http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/dotnetzip/examples.htm)

```
 using (ZipFile zip2 = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
 {
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip2)
    {
      if (e.FileName.EndsWith(".txt"))
      {
         var newname = e.FileName + "rename";
         e.FileName = newname;
      }
    }
    zip2.Save();
 }
```

Переименовываем все файлы с расширением `.txt`, добавляю к существующему названию каждого файла суффикс `rename`

Для вашего случая замените соответствующую строку на следующий код:

```
var newname = e.FileName.Substring(1, s.Length - 1); // первая замена
newname = newname.Replace("-l", "-w" ); // вторая замена
newname = "s" + newname; // третья замена
```

Comment: а как мне сделать Remove первой букву в название и + replace как в примере?
Какой файл из архива добавить?

Comment: @May_be внес изменения.

Comment: @May_be Какой файл из архива добавить? Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: ну там в архиве много .dll файлов, который(е) из них надо чтобы VS Zipfile не подчеркивал ?

Comment: VS написала что не может найти файл

Comment: using (ZipFile zip2 = ZipFile.Read("C:/Users/Csharp/Desktop/123/test.7Z/"))

Comment: почему вы пытаетесь скормить архив формата 7z, этот код для архива формата zip написан? В вашем вопросе вы спрашиваете про zip архив.

Comment: а разве 7z и zip это не одно и тоже? Тогда могу ли глянуть на 7z код, мне правда очень надо

Comment: нет, 7zip и "нормальный" zip это разные форматы. Код для 7z, хм, так сразу не скажешь, надо смотреть... Советую создать еще один вопрос, может кто-то вам поможет быстрее.

Comment: а вы не сможете?

Comment: @May_be: В этом вопросе никто не может. Вопрос про .zip, про него и ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [спецификации](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), имя файла хранится без сжатия в достаточно простой структуре Local File Header (4.3.7). Так что достаточно минимально разобрать файл и внести правки.